# Best way to replace value in pandas df based on list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF:

```
NAME  V ID
name1 0 424
name2 0 123
name3 1 241
```

And list:

```
list1 = ['name1', 'name4']
```

How can I in best way replace V in df to 1 if name is in list.
Example output:

```
NAME  V ID
name1 1 424
name2 0 123
name3 1 241
```

I tried to do it in for loop but it's not optimal way for df with 60k+ records, so I tried find another options, and I found something like this:

```
df.NAME[[x for x in range(len(df)) if x in list1]] = 1
```

But I don't think is the best way because it still for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will use , BTW do not name your `list` as `'list'`

```
df.loc[df.NAME.isin(['name1', 'name4']),'V']=1
df
    NAME  V   ID
0  name1  1  424
1  name2  0  123
2  name3  1  241
```

Comment: Ok, so that's like syntax of that operation looks like. I tred something simillar, but I do few mistakes as I see. Thank U very much for help. You saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 3):

First change variable name `list` to `L` because builtins and then replace by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership:

```
L = ['name1', 'name4']

df['V'] = np.where(df.NAME.isin(L), 1, df.NAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
my_list=['name1', 'name4']
df['V']=df['V'].mask(df['NAME'].isin(my_list),1)
print(df)

    NAME  V   ID
0  name1  1  424
1  name2  0  123
2  name3  1  241
```